# Memory utilization for multiple instance (SQL server 2008R2 standard edition)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, windows-server

If SQL Server 2008 R2 standard edition is limited to 64 GB of memory, then is it required to restrict the max memory for multiple instances (3) which are running SQL server 2008 R2 standard edition with 256 GB of RAM installed on windows server 2012?

Comment: Is this a physical host or virtual machine? I suggest you add `sql-server` tag as the question has nothing to do with ssms.  You can use ssms to set max memory.

Comment: This is a three node physical cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You can leave it to default for all instances because since it is SQL Server 2008 R2 standard edition it will not use more than 64 GB and you ahve total of 256 GB RAM so you are on safer side. Please also note that 64GB limitation is for `Database Engine` only other components like SSIS,SSAS,SSRS does not falls under this restriction and yes they can also consume good amount of memory.

Comment: Any impact on  internal memory pressure because some time PLE drops down very low.

Comment: PLE can drop down for many reason which necessarily does not means you have memory pressure. May be you are running massive index rebuild and other such queries are running requesting massive I/O in these cases PLE can fluctuate because buffer pool churns out more pages

Comment: No jobs schedule to run during day time also IO is not very high during PLE Drops